# cdap - cloudfusion - parse csv and apply schema

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to create a pipeline which performs following task.

1. read and parse the csv file
2. apply schema on top of that
3. records which are mapping schema is written to a valid bigquery table
4. records which doesn't match schema (i.e. if column expect int but in file it's string) it goes to reject bucket.

I have write following pipeline. However, the problem is, I don't see any records going to either rejected or bigquery.

if schema is not matching, shouldn't it go to reject?

[image]

Comment: Question, is the apply_schema step running, are the logs returning any information?

Comment: Schema mapping does not automatically happen, but needs to be explicitly performed in the apply_schema step. In particular, it should be done using send-to-error directives to check if various fields are what you expect them to be.